# How get Calendar app into 2.3.3 Emulator? (I'm using Google APIs level 10)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-calendar

I created a virtual device using the addon "Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2" but when i start up the emulator,  there's no calendar app. How do I get the calendar app on there? Is it in another addon somewhere? Do I have to download it form somewhere (where?) and install it via adb?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no Calendar by default in Android Emulators. Though, you can install them externally, via the `adb`. But, its advisable to better test it on your phone.

Nevertheless, check out this [Issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1389) for further assistance.